# JavaScript and JQuery - Shift + Enter for a new line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page wherein a user can click a button to post something. This works in a similar fashion as facebook.

When the user presses enter, the post will automatically be saved and displayed. When the user presses shift and enter, I was expecting a new line but it doesn't seem to work. I am using JQuery for that function. What could be wrong with this code ? I saw this solution while researching.

```
    $("#someTextArea").keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which == 13 && !event.shiftkey) {
        // ajax
    }
});
```

Comment: so does it resolve your problem or not?

Comment: I used the solution I found but it is not working. I wonder if JQuery behaves differently when event.shiftkey is used because on other examples, I saw that it is used in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `event.keyCode` and `event.shiftKey`(capital `K` [camel-case]);

---

**For your task something like this should do:**

```
var Keys = {
    ENTER: 13
};

$("#someTextArea").keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == Keys.ENTER) {
        if (event.shiftKey) {
            // make a new line
        } else {
            //submit the text
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It was such a simple mistake. Guess I have to have some rest for today. The code event.shitKey with capital k solved the problem.

Comment: Glad I could help. Have a nice rest